# Set style.background equal to linear-gradient in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css

I feel this is a daft question. I want to set a linear-gradient or radial-gradient on a DOM element in JavaScript.

If I try this:

```
div.style.background = "linear-gradient: (Red, Yellow)";
```

I get a blank/white div. Is this possible in javascript?

Link to JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/f8dhm57b/14/

Comment: `div.style.background = "linear-gradient(Red, Yellow)";` <-- typo

Comment: Some of you are good guys ;) Cheers!

Comment: It wasn't a typo, I genuinely didn't know how to do it. Imagine I was new, -3 votes would ban the account. Anyway cheers appreciate your time. Go vote up Spectre below as it's cost him rep just to help out.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Remove the `:`:

```js
const div = document.getElementById("myDiv");
div.style.background = "linear-gradient(Red, Yellow)";
```

```css
#myDiv {
  display: block;
  min-height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div id="myDiv">

</div>
```